Start Address of rpi-4-b .dtb file
On the official website I can't find the "start address" it used for loading device tree blob file, so I decide writing a program traversal all of memory find the entry it stored the .dtb magic number.
It worked ! But I still want to know the "correct way" to get the address ...
Thanks for any reply.
I write a program traversal memory and check each entry is same as magic number.

You need to study Documentation/arch/arm64/booting.rst and/or Documentation/arch/arm/booting.rst in the Linux kernel source regarding setting up the Device Tree. There is no fixed "start address", but there are rules.

I got it, thanks.
